# how can I easily copy text from a clickable text

Tags: windows, browser

is there a way to convert web link or clickable text to plain text 
for example, the youtube video title if I want to copy a word from the whole title it's hard and you might open the link 
so is there a keyboard key to prevent that, like converting it o reader mode

Answer (score 2):

Hold <kbd>alt</kbd> key when selecting the text. It will prevent the link from being clicked.

Tested with Chrome and Chromium based Edge.

Also works on Firefox

Comment: Nice. Works on Firefox as well.

Comment: +1 for you and the OP.